# Eclipse Product or Application

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to understand the difference between Eclipse Product and Eclipse application.
Lets take an example - I want to develop a tool named "Integration-Mapper". (It will provide user a graphical interface to draw classes in both the system and then will allow to MAP their attributes.) What should I go ahead with? Eclipse Product or Eclipse Application? and Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Eclipse application is a program, that can be executed in an Eclipse plug-in environment. This might or might not use the Rich Client Platform GUI, but the extensions and OSGi services from Eclipse can be re-used.

An Eclipse product on the other hand is a higher level concept: it is an Eclipse application, that (1) can be installed (at least using the p2 director application) separately, (2) can contain branding and launching information, and (3) can be packaged as a simple executable. Applications installed into such an executable (e.g. Eclipse IDE) can be launched using specific command line arguments, while the executable by default launches the selected application.

You should go ahead with both, as a Product always refers to an Application; and if I understand your need correctly, you want to add a deployable application for your users. That is something a product provides.